# how to display product on multiple widget using plugin

Tags: nopcommerce

I have plug in to display product using widget. I want to display product on multiple widget at same time.

e.g. I want to display product at `home_page_top`, `home_page_before_categories`, `home_page_before_best_sellers`, `home_page_before_news`, `home_page_before_poll` at the same time.

Still I have display my product using below code using single widget.

```
public IList<string> GetWidgetZones()
        {
return new List<string> { "home_page_top" };
}

 public void GetDisplayWidgetRoute(string widgetZone, out string actionName, out string controllerName, out RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
        {
            actionName = "list";
            controllerName = "product";
            routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary
            {
                {"Namespaces", "Nop.Plugin.product.product.Controllers"},
                {"area", null},
                {"widgetZone", widgetZone}
            };          
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
public IList<string> GetWidgetZones()
{
     return new List<string> { "home_page_top", 
         "home_page_before_categories",
         "home_page_before_best_sellers", 
         "home_page_before_news", 
         "home_page_before_poll"
     };
}
```